# How to extract a range of specific values from a matrix in R?

Tags: r, matrix

I've coded a matrix function for any integer, n. Now I would like to extract all the values 0.25 through 1.0 in the given matrix output. I'm only familiar with extracting elements based on the position in the matrix. What function do you recommend I use to do this? Thank you in advance; let me know if I need to include more information.

For n = 3:

```
        [,1]      [,2]      [,3]
[1,] 1.0000000 0.5000000 0.3333333
[2,] 0.5000000 0.3333333 0.2500000
[3,] 0.3333333 0.2500000 0.2000000
```

Comment: Show a (snippet of) your matrix so ppl see what the data looks like.

Comment: done! This particular matrix was created with n = 3; let me know if I need to include the coding used for the function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your matrix-producing function is something like this:

```r
make_matrix <- function(n) {
  do.call(cbind, lapply(seq(n) - 1, function(x) 1/(seq(n) + x)))
}
```

So we can make your matrix like this:

```r
m <- make_matrix(3)
m
#>           [,1]      [,2]      [,3]
#> [1,] 1.0000000 0.5000000 0.3333333
#> [2,] 0.5000000 0.3333333 0.2500000
#> [3,] 0.3333333 0.2500000 0.2000000
```

We can subset it the same way we subset a vector, since in R, a matrix is just a vector with an added `dim` attribute:

```r
m[m > 0.25]
#> [1] 1.0000000 0.5000000 0.3333333 0.5000000 0.3333333 0.3333333
```

We can also find out the positions of the numbers of interest by using `which`, as long as we add the parameter `arr.ind = TRUE`:

```r
which(m > 0.25, arr.ind = TRUE)
#>      row col
#> [1,]   1   1
#> [2,]   2   1
#> [3,]   3   1
#> [4,]   1   2
#> [5,]   2   2
#> [6,]   1   3
```